# How can I import data source from a different file in terraform?

Tags: terraform

My file structure is:

```
project_folder:
--- foo.tf
--- bar.tf
```

The thing is `data foo "example" {}` is defined in `foo.tf` and I'd like to reference it for a resource in `bar.tf` like:

```
resource "bar" "example" {
  name         = "bar-example"
  prop = "${foo.example.id}"
}
```

but I've got `unknown resource type` error in my IDE.

Comment: what exactly is foo.tf?

Answer (score 0):

I should have used "${data.foo.example.id}"`